# Difference between 那时，那时候，当时，那会儿，那阵子

Tags: grammar

I was trying to say "at that time I started to be interested in maths". I translated it as:

> 当时我开始对数学感兴趣.

Then I saw some other expressions to say "at that time": 那时，那时候，那会儿，那阵子.

What are the differences between those? I suppose 那会儿 is "at that moment" instead of "at that time" but what is the difference with 那时 and 那时候? And what is the meaning of 那阵子?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

那时/那时候 - formal, a long period of time. Whichever one you choose depends on how fast-paced you want your narration. 那时，我开始对数学感兴趣 makes the most sense because your growing interest in math sounds like a long-term process.

当时 - formal, a very short period of time. Example: 当时，我吓坏了。

那会儿 - colloquial, any length of time. Example: 那会儿，我在火车上只吃方便面。

那阵子 - colloquial, a very long period of time. Example: 那阵子，我特别无聊。

Answer (score 0):

那时, 那时候, 当时 is a point of time or time period that located times ago.

那阵子 is a time period that located times ago.

阵子 indicate period of times so 那阵子 specifically means a time period that located times ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

At that time, I started to get interested in maths.
那时我开始对数学感兴趣。

also

从那时起 ...

Answer (score 0):

"那时" is shorten of "那时候" , is same meaning of "當時"、"那會兒" = "At that time"

"那陣子" is similar to "during that time"

當時我嚇呆了= 那時(候)我嚇呆了 = "I was shocked at that time!"